# Server Side GET

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I want to merge a list into a show template on the server side.

How would I make a GET request to a list or a view from a show?  Do I have to call another library in the show to make a server side call or does couch have a native way to do this.  If a library, what is it?  I wish I could use couch.js server side basically.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, CouchDB does not have server-side functions like this. The requirement for _show and _list functions is a complete sandbox. The show or list must always return the same output for the same input. (This is to support HTTP caching.)

Comment: The solution here would be to create a view and list function that give you all the documents you want to process in a range.